# In JS Bach's lifetime who listened to any of his organ preludes and fugues and when?

Tags: history, j-s-bach

The related thread from Feb. 1, 2021 initiated by Aaron ([Who was listening to Bach's compositions in his lifetime?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/110395/70803)) was informative, but I have a more precise question. Who heard Bach's preludes and fugues for organ and when? Today we go to a recital in a church and sit in the pews and listen to a bunch of them. How were these works heard in Bach's time?

Comment: Today you can also hear the preludes and fugues played before or after a church service, which I suspect was their purpose in Bach's day.

Comment: The congregations of any of the churches he was employed to play at.

Comment: This question doesn't really add anything to the original. If you want clarification for a specific piece you can add a comment there.

Answer (score 11):

Bach was employed by churches for his entire working life, and a vast portion of his compositions were for the purpose of church services. He composed new material essentially every week, including his chorale preludes.

The "Preludes and Fugues" of his *Well-Tempered Clavier*, on the other hand, were composed as teaching pieces — a self-conscious part of the legacy he wanted to leave. They would have been played by his children, his wife Anna Magdalena, and other students he had.

Comment: But is there any evidence that the preludes and fugues were used in 18th century Lutheran church services as they are today, or that Bach played them in connection with church services?

Comment: @phoog that's a very specific thing to demand evidence of. Churches didn't generally keep any record of what their organist was playing. Even if you find an 18th century edition of _Preludes and Fugues_ in a Lutheran church there's no evidence of when it was actually used.

Comment: @OrangeDog perhaps not specific pieces that were played, but we know rather a lot of detail about the order of the Lutheran service, and we have specific performance dates for many of Bach's cantatas and other works.  If Bach played these fugues in connection with church services, or more generally if there was a practice of playing this sort of piece at a certain point (as there is today) then there's surely some document somewhere mentioning it.

Comment: @OrangeDog the main reason I'm asking is that most of Bach's organ music was composed when he was in and around Weimar, and for much of that time he was Kapellmeister at the ducal court, [where one young prince was a talented musician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Johann_Ernst_of_Saxe-Weimar).  The organ fugues could have been composed for entirely secular purposes.  They might have been study pieces for the prince.  They might have been entertainment for the ducal household.

Comment: @phoog the Well-Tempered Clavier was indeed composed for study pieces. Bach may not have played them at church himself, but any of his students or anyone else using it for study may well have also been employed as an organist while he was alive, and played one then.

Comment: @OrangeDog the question is about the organ preludes and fugues, not the WTC.  These are largely indexed [BWV 531 to 582](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_organ_compositions_by_Johann_Sebastian_Bach#In_the_form_of_a_Prelude,_Toccata,_Fantasia,_Passacaglia,_middle_movement_and/or_Fugue_(BWV_531%E2%80%93582)).

Comment: "Bach was employed by churches for his entire working life": in Weimar and Cöthen, he was employed in secular courts.  Cöthen, being a Calvinist court, didn't have church music.

Comment: *He composed new material essentially every week, including his chorale preludes.* This part of your answer is more accurate if you would say. He and his student's composed new pieces every week. Although just speculation his students helped him in his compositions a fair deal. Although it was under his supervision his student's input into his body of work was certainly greater than zero.

Comment: @NeilMeyer can you include a link to some discussion of this speculation? It's new to me. Can you suggest any examples from among Bach's output for weekly church services where a significant fraction of the composition is now thought to be by a student rather than by Bach himself?